# Footer with text on the left and text centered

Tags: html, css, footer

I am trying to create a footer with text on the left and text in the center (relative to the window's width).

For now, I have a footer with two divs with width 50% and text align left. Unfortunately, the text in the second div is not perfectly centered relative to the whole footer.

The solution is probably obvious, but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: Can you show us what code you have yet?

Comment: float the other div to the left. The other one, make its display inline-block and set its parent's text align to center.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
<div id="footer">
    <span class="left">
        Left
    </span>
    Center
</div>

<style>
    #footer {
        width:100%;
        text-align:center;
    }
    .left {
        float:left;
    }   
</style>
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y8g3j7qx/

Comment: Sorry I'm new and can't seem to select as answer or upvote you. But it did the trick, thanks a lot sir.

Comment: You have to wait a certain amount of minutes before you can accept an answer. Glad it helped